# Firebase Android SDK causes problems for loading fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase, push-notification

I imported an old Eclipse project with Android Studio. I used GCM for push notification. I'm trying to update this project by using Firebase. Just by adding Firebase dependency's into the gradle, I got a problem with some fragment. The app doesn't show, even load this fragments.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':wheel')
compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.8.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0' }


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 15

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try using 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
Sometimes, this latest library gives error.

Comment: Thanks it works ;)

Comment: Ok I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1' Sometimes, this latest library gives error.